# angularjs: $interval call never happen after it's cancelled

Tags: angularjs, setinterval

I've a requirement where as soon as i load a page it makes makes api call and 
 shows data on the page. and after every 15 sec it keeps loading the data an shows and i've a popup that has a click button function(ConfigModalButtonClick ). When i open the popup i wanted to stop the interval that makes the api call so for that i added $interval.cancel when popup is open but now when i click the button in popup the api call never happen. how can i make sure api call happens it looks like i need to call interval function again somewhere but not sure where??
the interval should run normally after 15 sec when i close the popup.

```
    $scope.timeDelay = 15000;       
    $scope.loadData = function() {

         $http.post(url,data
         ).then(
             function(response) {

                 $scope.output = response.data;

             },
             function(response) {

                 $scope.retrieveErrorMssg = "Failed to retrieve required data. Try again.";
             });
    };

    var interval = $interval(function() {
        $scope.loadData();

    }, $scope.timeDelay);

    $scope.showConfigurationModal = function() {

         $interval.cancel(interval);
         $scope.state.settingModalVisible = true;
    };

    $scope.closeConfigurationModal = function() {

        $scope.state.settingModalVisible = false;
        // Need to explicitly trigger the dismiss function of the modal
        $scope.settingModalDismiss();
    };      

    $scope.ConfigModalButtonClick = function () {

         $scope.state.settingModalVisible = false;            
         //some data manipulation


         $scope.loadData();          

    };
```

Comment: you might be getting error at loadData function . Please use control print to see if its being called

Comment: i didnt see the error

Comment: please print console ..

Comment: Not sure I understand. You cancel the interval before displaying the modal. So the interval is cancelled. Cancelled means cancelled. Won't run anymore. Why do you expect it to keep calling the API after you close the modal? If you want that to happen, you need to create another one by calling $interval again.

Comment: Read your own  subject line... it's pretty clear why it won't work again right from there. When you cancel a magazine subscription, do you expect them to still deliver it to you?

Comment: i think you have to call interval  on the **ConfigModalButtonClick** function

Comment: Yeah, but it also has a $scope.loadData(); function which would call the api with updated inputs from the popup but as soon as api call is done then i want to keep calling the api every interval but since its cancelled it doesn't get called and i am not sure how can call it again